# Change font style for dropdown menues in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I've Googled and searched, but I haven't been able to find much documentation on this. I'm aware that you can change the font size, but I'm wondering how to change the font itself. I believe the default is Times New Roman or something similar, but I want it to be the same font as the regular .btn class.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: i think the default font-family of bootstrap is sans-serif

Comment: Ah, thanks. Any idea on how to change the default? The .btn text and the .dropdown text is very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override Bootstrap's css in your own custom CSS stylesheet:

```
.dropdown-menu li{
   font-family:'my-awesome-font';
   font-size:16px
}
```

If needed, add the '!important' keyword, to be sure that the style takes priority.

Like user doniyor said, sans-serif is the default

```
//Bootstrap default font
font-family: sans-serif;
```

Comment: Could I just add those two lines to the original bootstrap.css?

`font-family:'my-awesome-font';
   
font-size:16px`

Comment: @Mitchyl you can also add ``!important;`` to make sure that it really overrides.